# REST API and web app on same project

Tags: node.js, api, rest, backbone.js, express

I created an express js REST API with the following end points,

```
/courses            [GET] [POST]
/courses/:id        [GET] [PUT] [DELETE]

/categories         [GET] [POST]
/categories/:name   [GET] [PUT] [DELETE]
/categories/:name/courses (return list of /courses/:id) [GET] [POST?]

/providers          [GET] [POST]
/providers/:name    [GET] [PUT] [DELETE]
/providers/:name/courses (return list of /courses/:id) [GET] [POST?]
```

A provider can have many courses and these courses belong to categories.

I'm trying to keep it all server side. Obviously I could use backbone or another framework to make my app SPA but my reasons for choosing everything server-side is because I don't want links with # hashtags.

I need this api for future implementetion. I'll re-use it in a mobile app.

How can I make the api and the webapp coexist in the same project? Do I have to repeat route logic? I'm trying to keep it DRY.

Would I have to use a library like ***request*** to make api calls?

E.g - www.app.com/courses/new would have to be linked to www.api.app.com/courses [GET]? How would I handle put and delete?

This all seems like a design problem.

Kind Regards.

Comment: use pushState if you don't want # in your uris

Comment: use ports and adapters so your webapp and your rest api can use the same port, but they can have different routing, domain, etc.... it's something similar as SimonPlus suggested.

Comment: Thank you. Would you then recommend Backbone over server side rendering? My main motivation for server side was the obvious # urls and speed.

Comment: I would use angular instead. It is easier to develop than backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect at the moment all your API logic is baked into the express rest api. The cleanest way to go in my opinion would be to decouple the API (as a module) so you can reuse it for your webapp.
[image: Structure]
So in the end:

- api.js does all the backend logic
- rest.js requires api.js
- webapp.js require api.js as well

Comment: Thanks SimonPlus.

In pratical means would api.js be equivalent to controller classes? In that way rest.js and webapp.js could call the controller methods. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant